# Passing data to an object

Tags: java, arraylist, parameter-passing

I'll list my code at the bottom, but here's the deal.
I have a parser class with a process method. This method scrapes data from a web page. I want to take each line of the scrape, split the string into an array and add the values to an object, then add the object to an ArrayList. As the loop iterates, new values from each line of the scrape are added to an ArrayList via the object. The relevent method in this code is public ArrayList process()

I'm getting the following compile errors:

The constructor Flight(String) is undefined
    Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after this token

The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Flight)

What am I doing wrong here, and how do if fix it?

```
public class HtmlParser {

public String url;
public String airline;
public static String lastFlight;
static ArrayList<String> capture = new ArrayList<String>();



public HtmlParser(Properties config) throws IOException{

    url = config.getProperty("url");
    airline = config.getProperty("airline");

    print("Fetching.........%s" , url);

}

public ArrayList<String> process() throws IOException{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Elements tableRow = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");

    for(Element tr : tableRow){
        if(tr.text().contains(airline)){
            String delims = "[ ]+";
            String singleRowArray[] = tr.text().split(delims);
            Flight f = new Flight(singleRowArray[]);
            capture.add(f);
        }
    }
    return capture;
}
```

Here's my flight Class.

```
public class Flight {

public Flight(String singleRowArray[]) {
    String origin = singleRowArray[0];
    String airline1 = singleRowArray[1];
    String airline2 = singleRowArray[2];
    String flightNo = singleRowArray[3];
    String date = singleRowArray[4];
    String ArrTime = singleRowArray[5];
    String status = singleRowArray[6];

}
```

}

Comment: Where did the top answer that was here go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The constructor Flight(String) is undefined Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after this token"

Try switching the brackets to the type, not the variable: `String[] singleRowArray`

"The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Flight)"

You have a `List<String>` where you want to input an object of type `Flight`, so you should change the list type to `List<Flight>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static ArrayList<String> capture = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can't add the Flight class object in capture list which can only contain element in String type.

```
     Flight f = new Flight(singleRowArray[]);
     capture.add(f);  // Issue
-----------------^
```